# Windows 7 on a brand new Toshiba laptop says only 768MB of RAM out of 3GB total ram is usable

Tags: windows-7

For a laptop with a Dual Processor and 64 Bit Win 7 Home Premium it has been sluggish for the three weeks I have owned it... today I opened up System in Control Panel and saw the listing for RAM I put up in the title.

The BIOS indicates the 3GB..

Answer (score 1):

Launch Resource Manager & take a look at your RAM. Does it illustrate your missing RAM as "system reserved"? When I had this problem, disabling hibernate fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean is says  "3.00 GB (768 GB usable)" On the System main page?

You have a real hardware problem call Toshiba, either get a full refund or another unit, don't send it in for repairs.

.